# Scheduled Audio Playback at Specific Times in a Flutter App

Tags: flutter

How can I implement scheduled audio playback at specific times within a Flutter application, such as 8:00 AM, 12:00 PM, and 6:00 PM, while ensuring continued functionality even when the app is in a background or sleep mode?

Are there any Flutter-specific configuration settings or packages available for managing time-related and clock-checking tasks to maintain app wakefulness and facilitate scheduled audio playback?